# Check if $\min|f(x)-g(x)|$ is a metric.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have this problem:
Let C(K) denote the set of continuous functions $f:K\to\mathbb{R}$, where $K =[a,b]$. Is $d(f,g)=\inf_{a\leq x\leq b} |f(x)-g(x)|$ a metric?

I am stuck. I know that $d(f,g)\geq 0$, $d(f,g)=d(g,f)$ and $d(f,g)=0 \Leftarrow f=g$ are trivial, but checking if $d(f,g)=0 \Rightarrow f=g$ leads me to $0=d(f,g)\leq |f(x)-g(x)|$ and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Also $d(f,g)\leq d(f,h)+d(h,g)$ seems off because $\inf (|f-h|+|h-g|)\geq \inf |f-h|+\inf|h-g|$...

Comment: The condition $d(f,g)=0$ does not imply $f=g.$ Moreover for $f=0,$ $g=1$ and $h=x$ we have $d(f,g)=1$ but $d(f,h)=0$ and $d(h,g)=0,$ when $[a,b]=[0,1].$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x $ for $x $ in $ [0,1] $ and $g(x)=0 $ in $[0,1]$. $f$ and $g $ belongs to $C[0,1]$ and $ \inf\{|f(x)-g(x)|: x \in [0,1]\}=0 $ but $f$ is not equal to $g$. Hence, it is not a metric on $C[0,1]$.